# GET query string parameters from .htaccess rewrite URL in PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

In my website, I am trying to rewrite few of my URLs as bellow:

This URL

`http://example.com/news.php?newstype=newsletter&newsid=1123&newstitle=my news title`

int to:

`http://example.com/newsletter/1123/my news title`

My rewrite rule in `.htaccess` looks like as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]
```

My `<a>` tag is looks this:

```
$seoUrl = "$urlNewsType/$newsid/$urlNewsTitle/";
$seoUrl = urldecode($seoUrl);
$seoUrl = html_escape($seoUrl, 'UTF-8');

<a href="$seoUrl">Read More</a>
```

These every things are working for me. But my question is, I need to get these query string parameters separately from URL into PHP. Problem is I can't get these prameters as I do usually.

In php, This is the output of:
`echo '<pre>',print_r($_GET).'</pre>';`

```
Array
(
  [newstype] => news/1114
  [newsid] => Presentation: Heath+Day+in+2018
  [newstitle] => 
)
```

Can anybody tell me, what is the wrong which I have done in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern `(.*)` is greedy. It matches the full requested path. Try `([^/]+)` instead :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?newstype=$1&newsid=$2&newstitle=$3 [L,QSA,NC,B]
```